# about a replaceText function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following jQuery replaceText function, can someone please explain to me what the line `remove.length && $(remove).remove();` does? I don't understand the usage of && here.

```
$.fn.replaceText = function( search, replace, text_only ) {  
  return this.each(function(){  
    var node = this.firstChild,  
      val,  
      new_val,  
      remove = [];  
    if ( node ) {  
      do {  
        if ( node.nodeType === 3 ) {  
          val = node.nodeValue;  
          new_val = val.replace( search, replace );  
          if ( new_val !== val ) {  
            if ( !text_only && /</.test( new_val ) ) {  
              $(node).before( new_val );  
              remove.push( node );  
            } else {  
              node.nodeValue = new_val;  
            }  
          }  
        }  
      } while ( node = node.nextSibling );  
    }  
    remove.length && $(remove).remove();  
  });  
};
```

Comment: Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10688568/601179) don't copy the author mistake, it's poor use of jQuery. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way conditions short circuit, `$(remove).remove();` will only be evaluated if `remove.length` is *true-ish*.

Since `remove` is declared as an array, it's basically the same as:

```
if(remove.length != 0)
   $(remove).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` here means that `$(remove).remove()` will only be executed if `remove.length` isn't 0.

This is because the `&&` is a short circuit operator so it will not evaluate whatever comes after it if what is before it evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

Though you got some right answers about what it does:

```
if(remove.length) // length is bigger than 0 (in this context)
   $(remove).remove();
```

I must say that code is **stupid**, jQuery knows how to handle empty sets.
So when `$(remove).length == 0` the code `$(remove).remove();` just won't do anything.

You can simply use it without the `if`:

```
$(remove).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

it says :

if remove.length returns something other than 0 (which is equivalent to false) then remove the  element

Answer (score 0):

It is making sure that the "remove" object is set

```
if(remove.length != 0)
```

so that it does not try to remove something that does not exist. In jQuery, if the object $(remove) does not exist, the .length function will return 0 which coincides with False in javascript.

If it does exist (remove.length > 0) then it will be removed using the .remove() function. The naming is ambiguous for sure.

It's basically an in line condition statement to prevent an exception by calling .remove() on an object that doesn't exist.